# Open --> Setting --> Project Properties will shut down Qgis

Tags: qgis

When I want change my project and I select setting and the project properties .
It's will give me some message, like "Exception - Bad allocation" 
How do fix the problem ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjycz.jpg

Comment: No need to put your email on the question.  Unless you want to get spammed by the bots that crawl the interwebs

Comment: It would help to have more information like the platform QGIS is installed on, details about the install, etc.  For instance, are you using the stand-alone QGIS installer, or the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer?
This sort of information will help generate a better answer to your question.

Comment: I think I recall reading about such behavior but it should have been fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, so you'll probably want to report it to the QGIS bug tracker which you can find here:
http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

If it is a bug they'll be able to fix it for everyone. Be sure to provide as much information as you can. There are some good generic "how do I report a bug" web-pages around:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-to-write-good-bug-report/